# Whether replicationFactor=2 makes sense in SolrCloud?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, solrcloud

We are trying to building our solr cloud servers, we want to increase replicationFactor, but don't want to set it as 3 as we have a lot of data.

So I am wondering whether it makes sense to set replicationFactor as 2, and what's the impact, whether this will cause problem for replica leader election such as split brain etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replicationFactor will not affect whether a split brain situation arises or not. The cluster details are stored in Zookeeper. As long as you have a working Zookeper ensemble Solr will not have this issue. This means you should make sure you have 2xF+1 zookeper nodes (minimum 3) . 
From [zookeeper documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html):

> For the ZooKeeper service to be active, there must be a majority of
>   non-failing machines that can communicate with each other.
>
> To create a deployment that can tolerate the failure of F machines,
>   you should count on deploying 2xF+1 machines.

Here are some links explaining it further:

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SolrCloud-and-split-brain-tp3989857p3989868.html

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Whether-replicationFactor-2-makes-sense-tp4300204p4300206.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, jay. It totally makes sense. btw, Erick also provided some good insight at http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Whether-replicationFactor-2-makes-sense-td4300204.html

Comment: Thats a much better explanation than mine :) . Updated the answer with Erick's explanation